# Scala future for comprehension with another future in yield

Tags: scala, future

I have this code:

```
def getFutureResult() : Future[Long] = {
    val f1 = service.getFutureR1()
    val f2 = service.getFutureR2()
    val f3 = service.getFutureR3()

    for {
        r1 <- f1
        r2 <- f2
        r3 <- f3
        } yield {
        if (combine(r1,r2,r3))
            service.getFutureR100()
        else
            service.getFutureR200()
        }

}
```

Every service methods return a Future[Long].
Of course, the for statement returns a Future[Future[Long]] and the code doesn't compile properly. 
I have two solutions, this is the first one:

```
def getFutureResult() : Future[Long] = {
    val f1 = service.getFutureR1()
    val f2 = service.getFutureR2()
    val f3 = service.getFutureR3()

    val ffresult = for {
        r1 <- f1
        r2 <- f2
        r3 <- f3
        } yield {
        if (combine(r1,r2,r3))
            service.getFutureR100()
        else
            service.getFutureR200()
        }

    ffresult.flatMap(identity)    
}
```

And this is the second one:

```
def getFutureResult() : Future[Long] = {
    val f1 = service.getFutureR1()
    val f2 = service.getFutureR2()
    val f3 = service.getFutureR3()

    val ffresult = for {
        r1 <- f1
        r2 <- f2
        r3 <- f3
        } yield {
        val fresult = if (combine(r1,r2,r3))
            service.getFutureR100()
        else
            service.getFutureR200()
        }
        Await.result(fresult,10 seconds)
}
```

What is the best solution? Are there any other solution?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 5):

Just add one more stage to for:

```
for {
    r1 <- f1
    r2 <- f2
    r3 <- f3
    result <- (
        if (combine(r1,r2,r3)) service.getFutureR100()
        else service.getFutureR200())
} yield result
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll use this solution.
Other question: Is my second solution (using await) blocking? Or it doesn't block because the await is inside another future.

Comment: @jfabaf It blocks until `f1`, `f2` and `f3` are ready, but doesn't block for `service.getFutureR100()` or `service.getFutureR200()`

Answer (score 0):

Why not `rs` inside the for-comprehension.

```scala
val ffresult = for {
    r1 <- service.getFutureR1()
    r2 <- service.getFutureR2()
    r3 <- service.getFutureR3()
    rs <- if (combine(r1,r2,r3))
      service.getFutureR100()
    else
      service.getFutureR200()
    } yield rs
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll use this solution.
Other question: Is my second solution (using await) blocking? Or it doesn't block because the await is inside another future.

Comment: If you `await`, you are blocking in some way.